# scroll left after onclick load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, load

i have a problem with a horizontal website.
by clicking it switches a div with content. but if scrolled to the far right the new content is out of sight to the left. this is what i've done:

```
<a href="#" class="img" onclick="$('div.container').hide().load('test.html').fadeIn(1500);return false;.scrollLeft()";><img src="images/1.jpg" / height="200px"></a>
```

is there a possibility to do it in the on click action? or in the test.html to load this action?

```
.animate({'left':'+=50'});
```

worked so far, but no to put the scrolling to 0. it sometimes added some to the left...

thanks in advance!
cheers, nico

Comment: could you post a JSFiddle as your question is a little unclear

Comment: there are multiple files loaded within.
so i dont know how to